# Like all databases on the server for a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a statement but it queries a database that I insert in the variable "USE", I need it to read all the databases hosted in sys.databases:

```
USE [BD001]
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName,
       'guest' AS Database_User,
       [permission_name],
       [state_desc]
FROM sys.database_permissions
WHERE [grantee_principal_id] = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID('guest')
  AND [state_desc] LIKE 'GRANT%'
  AND [permission_name] = 'CONNECT'
  AND DB_NAME() NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'msdb');
```

I thought I could create a variable but I can't...and I can't figure out how to do it.

Is there any way to make this query generic so that I can insert other test queries?

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(1000) 
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT name 
FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'msdb' )

OPEN database_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = '
     
     SELECT '''  + @DB_Name + ''' AS DatabaseName,
       ''guest'' AS Database_User,
       [permission_name],
       [state_desc]
FROM ' +@DB_Name+ '.sys.database_permissions
WHERE [grantee_principal_id] = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(''guest'')
  AND [state_desc] LIKE ''GRANT%''
  AND [permission_name] = ''CONNECT'''


     
     EXEC sp_executesql @Command 

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END 

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

Comment: White space and line breaks are a most for readable code too. One long wide line is not easy to read.

Comment: *"I have a statement but it queries a database that I insert in the variable "USE""* `USE` can't be parametrised. `USE @Database;` would very likely give you the error `Incorrect syntax near '@Database'.` You'll need to use dynamic SQL here if you want to perform this query against multiple databases and **safely** inject the database's name into the dynamic statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following cursor may help you;

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(1000) 
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT name 
FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'msdb' )

OPEN database_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = '
     
     SELECT '''  + @DB_Name + ''' AS DatabaseName,
       ''guest'' AS Database_User,
       [permission_name],
       [state_desc]
FROM ' +@DB_Name+ '.sys.database_permissions
WHERE [grantee_principal_id] = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID(''guest'')
  AND [state_desc] LIKE ''GRANT%''
  AND [permission_name] = ''CONNECT'''


     
     EXEC sp_executesql @Command 

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END 

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Is there any way to make this query generic so that I can insert other test queries? For example:SELECT name, is_disabled FROM sys.server_principals where name='sa'

Comment: EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') BEGIN USE ?     SELECT ''?'', is_disabled FROM sys.server_principals where name=''sa'' END'

Comment: Is there any way to count the result of the query?

Comment: You can try this but ıt will be helpful to add
this questions into your post

CREATE TABLE ##TempTable 
(Col1 VARCHAR(100), Col2 INT)
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') BEGIN USE ? INSERT INTO ##TempTable SELECT ''?'', 
is_disabled FROM sys.server_principals where name=''sa'' END'
SELECT * FROM ##TempTable